# What am I doing wrong here? IF and Else statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My goal here is to read through a bunch of rows which are now in records. If the second column of any record (row[1]) is equal to 133 in this example it prints out the first and second column.

I am running into this issue though:

line 11 - else: issue

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
print "Opened database successfully";

cur = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM sightings")
row = cur.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    if row[1] == 133:
        print row[0], row[1] 
    else:
        row = cur.fetchone():


cur.close()

conn.close()
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: SQL! Just fetch the record you need.

Comment: I am moving onto the next record if not found.

Comment: You can use `""SELECT * FROM sightings WHERE (name_of_the_column) = 133"`

Comment: Why is there a colon after `cur.fetchone()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra colon at the end of a statement that you do not need

```
if row[1] == 133:
    print row[0], row[1] 
else:
    row = cur.fetchone(): <----
```

Should be..

```
if row[1] == 133:
    print row[0], row[1] 
else:
    row = cur.fetchone()
```

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to fix it with some help from you guys. thank you!

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
print "Opened database successfully";

cur = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM sightings WHERE column = 133")
row = cur.fetchone()

while row is not None:

        print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]  
        row = cur.fetchone()



cur.close()

conn.close()
```